# \addbibresource doesn't work with file contents

Tags: biblatex, citing, filecontents

I want to cite using the `\filecontents` command for the books.

But it doesn't recognize the books. It only shows the keyword in bold.
It says citation "elch" is undefined

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
    \usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}

    \usepackage{filecontents}


    \begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
    @BOOK{elch,
    AUTHOR = "Karall, Benedikt and Schwarz, Markus",
    TITLE = "{Eine Studie zur Elchplicht}",
    PUBLISHER = "JG-Verlag",
    YEAR = 2012}
    \end{filecontents}


    \usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{ref.bib}

    \begin{document}

    Die exakte Herleitung kann in \parencite{elch} nachgelesen werden.

   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just checked your MWE, it works for me. Did you run Biber? See [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: If you did in fact run Biber, you will find a `.blg` file. What does it say?

Comment: I have run pdflatex and bibtex (in texmaker there is no fiber option9 and then twice pdflatex

Comment: @moewe I changed the settings to biber. I used the tutorial in your link and now it says could not start the command biber.exe

Comment: Looks like you don't even have Biber installed. If you run MikTeX install it via the Package Manager. If you use TeX live install it via `tlmgr`. Then do an update (on MikTeX in both User and Admin mode) and try again.

Comment: I don't know how, but i finally managed to get backend=biber working... Had to reset the settings, because I really messed up the paths.. I have just put "biber" % in the path... without endings because with .exe or bcf it didn't work.